# How can i change app.template.html to index.html in .nuxt/views folder

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using NuxtJS v2 and I'm having an issue trying to rename the file *app.template.html* to *index.html* in .nuxt/views folder.
i've looked into the documentation in [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#filenames) but with no progress, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `.nuxt` folder is automatically generated by Nuxt - you are not supposed to modify any file there as it will be overwritten next time you (re)start Nuxt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and yes i'm aware of this behavior, and i do want the file name to be changed to index.html on every build of the project, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why do you want such thing? You could always use a post build script with some `mv` command in there.

Comment: @kissu for DevOps purposes, i want the entry point for the project to be index.html, as in a normal VueJS project (dist/index.html), but in NuxtJS there's no index.html

Comment: Because you're looking for `index.html` into `.nuxt` instead of `/dist`. Just run `npm run generate` and watch the magic happens.

Comment: `npm run generate` is for target: static, my project is target: SSR, `npm run genrate` wouldn't work in that case, i have to use `npm run build`